# What kind of authentication does JDBC connection use?

Tags: database, authentication, jdbc

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm

We provide user id and password to the JDBC connection. What kind of authentication method is that user id and password.

For example, for SQL server, we know there is Windows Authentication, SQL Authentication. Which one the JDBC connection is used?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-url-sample

How about to other databases? Maybe a wrong question?

Comment: For which database (and driver), there is no general "JDBC authentication", this is specific to the combination of database and driver.

Answer (score -1):

If you provide an username and a password it must be SQL Authentication.

If want to use Windows Authentication you need to build up your database-url to be something like `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=true;`